# delete where id is the biggest

Tags: mysql

I would like to detele the row with the biggest order_id, I tried this:

```
DELETE FROM orders WHERE MAX(order_id)
```

But this is wrong! any other ideas?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `WHERE order_id = MAX(order_id)`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First idea (among many others that had exactly the same):

```
DELETE FROM orders 
WHERE order_id = 
      ( SELECT MAX(order_id)
        FROM orders
      )
```

Unfortunately MySQL complains with:

```
> ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'orders' for update in FROM
> clause
```

Two ways to bypass the error:

```
DELETE FROM orders 
WHERE order_id =
       ( SELECT maxo
         FROM  
           ( SELECT MAX(order_id) AS maxo
             FROM orders
           ) AS tmp
        )
```

or:

```
DELETE FROM orders
ORDER BY order_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 8):

For MySQL, this would be easiest:

```
DELETE FROM orders
ORDER BY order_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You can't do the subquery trick that several other people have answered, because MySQL doesn't like it if you select from a table and update/delete from it in the same query.

Comment: Simple and effective, this is the way to go :) no hassles

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
DELETE FROM orders where order_id = (select max(order_id) from orders)
```

Comment: I get this erro: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'orders' for update in FROM clause

Comment: I just tried this and it does work, what database are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
DELETE FROM orders where order_id = (SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM orders)
```

Answer (score -1):

try a subquery.

```
DELETE FROM orders WHERE order_id = (SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM orders)
```

Comment: I get this error: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'orders' for update in FROM clause

Comment: meh, mysql, huh. You can't update a table that's mentioned in a sub-select. Not sure if there is a single-statement way around this, you might have to wrap the SELECT and DELETE in a transaction in the application.

Comment: I have an idea how to do this with PHP but first I wanted to ask you guys to see if there is a better to do it with one mysql statement but anyways thank you for your time and help