# Delete oldest row when count reaches 25 PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Trying to figure out how to accomplish the following. I have a count set up to count rows in database. Based off that code I want to be able to delete one row in data base when count reaches a certain number. Any suggestions?

```
$post_query_count = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$find_count = mysqli_query($connection, $post_query_count);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($find_count);

if($count = 25) {
 $query_delete = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE LIMIT 1";
  mysqli_query($connection, $query_delete);
}
```

Comment: Presumably you mean `if($count == 25) {`?

Comment: I don't think your requirement makes much sense but you could delete the row with the highest or lowest id, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6550922/982075

Comment: Also instead of querying all data you could just `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts` and then fetch that data. Doesn't make a significant difference for 25 rows but still you're querying data that you don't care about.

Comment: `DELETE FROM posts WHERE LIMIT 1` is not valid SQL syntax. Either drop `where` or add a condition to it.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice! the added equal sign and adding a condition worked!

`if($count == 5) {
  $query_delete = "DELETE FROM posts ORDER BY post_date LIMIT 1";
  mysqli_query($connection, $query_delete);
}`